# why setcookie doesnt work in live website but it works in localhost?

Tags: php, codeigniter, setcookie

I have a captcha script on

[captcha link](http://www.arcticpost.net/ap/user/create_captcha/)

it uses following code:

```
include 'kcaptcha/kcaptcha.php';
$path = "/";
//this line will produce captcha image
$captcha = new KCAPTCHA();
//writing the cookie so that we can check on next page



//captcha value save as md5 encryption so that when validating is should make md5 mask to captcha form input
setcookie("captcha", md5($captcha->getKeyString()), time()+1000, $path);
```

This code works on localhost but doesnt work on my live website. What is wrong?

Thank You

Comment: Outputting the image data, *then* sending the cookie, are we? Use a hexeditor and peek at the trailing garbage (you've got two pretty html error messages) after the image data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: If that was the case, it wouldn't work locally. I'm guessing he's outputting the image later. Where is the script installed on your server? If it's /scripts/myscript.php or something then the $path = "/" wouldn't work. You could also try setting the domain value (the next parameter) to ".mydomain.com".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the domain entered properly in $config['cookie_domain'] in config/config.php?